# How would you compress 256-byte string consists of only "F" and "G"?

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding, binary, compression

Theoretically, how much you can compress this 256-byte string containing only "F" and "G"?

`FGFFFFFFGFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGFFGFGGGFFFGGGGGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGFFFGFGGFGFFFFGFFGFGGFFFGFGGFGFFFGFGGGGFGGGGGGGGGFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGFFFFFGFFGGGGGGGFFFGGGFFGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGGGFFGFFGFGFFGFFGFFFFGGGGFGGFGGGFFFGGGFFFGGGFFGGFFGGGGFFGFGGFFFGFGGF`

While I don't see a real world application, it is intriguing that compression algorithms like gz, bzip2 and deflate have a disadvantage in this case.
Well, I have this answer and the C# code to demonstrate:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string testCase = "FGFFFFFFGFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGFFGFGGGFFFGGGGGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGFFFGFGGFGFFFFGFFGFGGFFFGFGGFGFFFGFGGGGFGGGGGGGGGFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGFFFFFGFFGGGGGGGFFFGGGFFGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGGGFFGFFGFGFFGFFGFFFFGGGGFGGFGGGFFFGGGFFFGGGFFGGFFGGGGFFGFGGFFFGFGGF";
        uint[] G = new uint[8]; // 256 bit

        for (int i = 0; i < testCase.Length; i++)
            G[(i / 32)] += (uint)(((testCase[i] & 1)) << (i % 32));

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(G[i]);

        string gTestCase = string.Empty;

        //G 71  0100 0111
        //F 70  0100 0110
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            gTestCase += (char)((((uint)G[i / 32] & (1 << (i % 32))) >> (i % 32)) | 70);

        Console.WriteLine(testCase);
        Console.WriteLine(gTestCase);

        if (testCase == gTestCase)
            Console.WriteLine("OK.");
    }
}
```

It may sound silly, but as to how I can improve the algorithm so that this 256-bit decimal number can be further compressed, I have the following idea:
(Note: The following are different topics of discussion but related to compressing 256-byte further)

From my understanding of Microsoft's implementation of [`Decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal),

> 96-bit + 96-bit = 128-bit decimal.

Which implies that a 192-byte string containing of any two distinct characters can be encoded as 128-bit number instead of 192-bit number. Correct?

My questions are:

1. **Can I do the same with 256-byte strings?**
   (by splitting each of them into a pair of two numbers before adding those two as a `Decimal` shorter than 256-bit)?
2. **How do I decode the above-mentioned 128-bit `Decimal` back to a pair of two 96-bit numbers**, while maintaining the compressed data size less than 192-bit?

Sorry for my previous rather vague question.

The following code would demonstrate how to add two 96-char "binary" strings as 128-char binary string.

```
public static string AddBinary(string a, string b) // 96-char binary strings
{
    int[] x = { 0, 0, 0 };
    int[] y = { 0, 0, 0 };

    string c = String.Empty;

    for (int z = 0; z < a.Length; z++)
        x[(z / 32)] |= ((byte)(a[a.Length - z - 1]) & 1) << (z % 32);
    for (int z = 0; z < b.Length; z++)
        y[(z / 32)] |= ((byte)(b[b.Length - z - 1]) & 1) << (z % 32);

    decimal m = new decimal(x[0], x[1], x[2], false, 0); //96-bit
    decimal n = new decimal(y[0], y[1], y[2], false, 0); //96-bit
    decimal k = decimal.Add(m, n);
    int[] l = decimal.GetBits(k); //128-bit      

    Console.WriteLine(k);

    for (int z = 127; z >= 0; z--)
        c += (char)(((l[(z / 32)] & (1 << (z % 32))) >> (z % 32)) | 48);

    return c.Contains("1") ? c.TrimStart('0') : "0";
}
```

Comment: And what is your answer?

Comment: What happens if you encode F and G as a series of 0s and 1s?

Comment: @user3386109. The following are my findings: gz = 79 bytes (324%)
bzip2 = 94 bytes (272%)
deflate = 67 bytes (382%).  My answer is theoretically it can be stored as 256-bit number. Thanks for asking.

Comment: You can definitely store it a a 256-bit number. If there are dependencies between the characters, then it can even be stored more compact. Although that will in this case likely not (significantly) reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: There is a difference though: you cannot decode the bit stream without implicit knowledge of encoding. For a short sequence like that, the over head cost is quite big.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "theoretically, how much can it be compressed?". One meaning could be "what's the shortest program (in some fixed programming language) that can reproduce the string (aka Kolmagorov Complexity). Answered naively, you can invent a compression algorithm that encodes the given string as the empty string.

Comment: Yes, my question is quite vague, I am also trying to understand it myself. I have another related question (which I don't want to post as separate question): AFAIK, 96-bit + 96-bit = 128-bit decimal.  If I have 192-byte string of two distinct characters, would it be considered a great savings by converting it to two pair of 96-bit number and add it as 128-bit number, instead of 192-bit number?  If so, can I split 256-bit to two pair of decimal number and add it as a number shorter than 256-bit? Thank you. I acknowledged every comments above.

Comment: If you were able to magically encode 192 bits into 128 bits you would be set for life, so no, that is not possible. 192 bits can be encoded as ... 192 bits. Compression works by reducing typical patterns, at the cost of expansion for the less typical patterns, but you will never be guaranteed to be able to encode 192 bits as 128 bits.

Comment: Think about it. If I were able to encode 192 bits (= 24 bytes) into 128 bits (=16 bytes), then I could take a 1MB file (=1048576 bytes) and encode every group of 24 bytes into 16 bytes, reducing the file down to 699056 bytes, reduce that further down to 466040 bytes, and then after 28-29 steps be down to 16 bytes. That would be the holy grail of compression. ANY file could be reduced down to 16 bytes.

Comment: I think the main thing I'm not really understanding is what you mean by a "X-bit decimal". What does that mean, exactly?

Comment: Hi @LasseV.Karlsen, I appreciate your replies. Made me glad. I mean the difficult part is how to embed decoding information in the 128-bit, as long as it is below 192-bit, that is acceptable.

Comment: As to what is "X-bit decimal", here's the code I wrote not long ago, on how to add two 96-char binary strings as 128-char binary string. (I'm not sure if I can paste the code on here).

Comment: How would doing *arithmetic* (`add`ing) on bit-sets *mean* anything?

Comment: Where do those `96-bit` entities come from?

Comment: Hi @greybeard. Each 96-bit can be concatenated with 3 instances of 32-bit unsigned integer, or 12 instances of 8-bit ASCII code. Maybe you're right about it, adding two decimal numbers may not mean anything. That's why I am asking if I can decode a 128-bit decimal with minimal additional bits of information after encoding two pairs of 96-bit decimal together.

Comment: You do not have (2×?)`12 instances of 8-bit [codes]`, you have (1×) 256 characters. You are confusing me, if nobody else, with `two pairs` - that would be *four* items, wouldn't it? I do not know what to make of `96-bit + 96-bit = 128-bit decimal`: where did you get that from?

Comment: @greybeard, each character is formed by 8-bit code, so 96-bit data effectively can store up to 12 characters (or more, depending on the context). As for the 128-bit decimal, you can refer to this MSDN documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=netframework-4.8    Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Sorry for my broken English. What I mean is if there are only two distinct characters in any binary file, it can be converted from X-byte length to X-bit length with a few bytes of dictionary to decode. That is every 8 bytes compressed as 1 byte.  What I am mainly asking is, adding two 96-bit number will result in 128-bit number, but I am having difficulty to substract the 128-number back into two 96-bit number without making it greater than 192-bit number in total. (128 + 96 > 192)

Comment: @bookm 96bit+96bit is not 128 bit ... if it is then a loss of information occurs which in fixed/floating point numbers is called rounding error. That is not how compression works ... If you want further improve compression ratio then try RLE (run length encoding PCX) or LHARC (dictionary based GIF) however as in any loss-less compression scheme you can expect that some data might be encoded with bigger size than raw data ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > 96-bit + 96-bit = 128-bit decimal.

That is a misunderstanding. `Decimal` is 96bit *integer*/*mantissa*, a sign and an exponent from 0 to 28 (~5bit) to form a scaling factor for the mantissa.
Addition is from 2×(1+5+96) bits to 1×(1+5+96) bits, including inevitable rounding errors and overflow.

You can't get summands from a sum easily - for starters, addition is symmetrical, there is no earthly way of knowing which of two summands has been the first and which the second.

[Paul Hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341896/how-would-you-compress-256-byte-string-consists-of-only-f-and-g#comment104882894_59341896) mentioned the programmer's variant of compressibility: [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).
In all fairness, you'd have to add to the 256 bits of your *recoding* of the input string the size of a program to turn those bits into the original string.
(As would *gz, bzip2, deflate(, [LZW](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch))* - decoders for "pure LZ" can be *very* small. The usual escape is to define a [file format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Identifying_file_type), including a recognisably *header*.)

[Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341896/how-would-you-compress-256-byte-string-consists-of-only-f-and-g#comment104885241_59341896) mentioned one consequence of the [Pigeon-hole principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): to tell each combination of 192 bits from every other one, you need no less than 2^192 codes.